# codenameone video in landscape is not filling screen

Tags: video, codenameone, media, landscape

I'm working on a CodeName One app which includes a video player.
I've setup my form layout using the new gui builder and a Constraint layout.
in which I have a borderlayout container which should fill the entire with of the display.
In my code I'm creating a MediaPlayer and adding it to the center of the container (I have also tried North).
The issue is when the app is in landscape the video is not filling the width of the screen. In Portrait it is working as expected.
Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Here's a screenshot from the simulator showing the issue;
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A more common approach is using a size change listener on the `Form` to automatically switch to native player mode when `Display.isPortrait()` is `false`. I would also suggest having a magnifier icon that would do that manually.

You can do this with `setNativePlayerMode(true)`